# TE_find_text returning ascii characters in certain machines

Tags: loadrunner, rte

I have recorded some scripts in legacy system(telnet, vt100) and I use TE_find_text to verify some of the contents on the screen. It all works fine in my machine. But when it is run on other ones, ASCII characters are returned and TE_find_text fails without finding the expected text.

What could be the possible solution for this? The machine in which it works is core i7 laptop. Has anyone faced the similar situation?

Comment: Define "other ones..."  Load Generators....other VUGEN hosts....from the MDRV command line....different versions of LoadRunner.....different versions of operating system but same version of LoadRunner....?  Help us to qualify the differences between the known good machine and the unknown hosts

Comment: Hello James, Load runner version is the same.And we're using a community edition. It is 12.55. We tried in intel Xeon x-64 based laptops and they are having issues in finding text. Only laptop it works is on core i7 (windows 7 service pack1), 64-bit operating system.

Comment: could you please add the expected result and the actual result. Also please include the language settings (Language for non-unicode programs) of both machines.